# Adding a loopback interface

Tags: networking, iproute

I would like to "overwrite" IP addresses that already exists on the public internet. So, I want to create multiple loopback interfaces on a machine, so I can ping any IP address that I configure from other machines in the same local network, as long as there is a static route configured to the machine containing the loopbacks.

What would be the best method, using `iproute2`? It seems I can create a `dummy` interface, but also a `veth` (virtual Ethernet) interface. Is one of these the best solution, or would something else be preferred?

Answer (score 0):

So, it seems that just adding more subnets to the `lo` interface works perfectly fine:

`ip addr add 192.168.40.1/32 dev lo`, which makes this address reachable to the outside world.